# Spring Data Mongodb findBy In case insensitive

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest, case-insensitive

I'm trying to create a Spring Data MongoDB repository method that could perform case insensitive search for fields from a given list, that is functionality similar to SQL 'IN' operator.

In my repository I have following methods:

```
User findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
User findByUsernameIgnoreCase(@Param("username") String username);
Page<User> findByUsernameIn(@Param("username") List<String> username, Pageable pageable);
Page<User> findByUsernameIgnoreCaseIn(@Param("username") List<String> username, Pageable pageable);
Page<User> findByUsernameInIgnoreCase(@Param("username") List<String> username, Pageable pageable);
Page<User> findByUsernameInAllIgnoreCase(@Param("username") List<String> username, Pageable pageable);
```

I'm also exposing repository as REST resource using `@RepositoryRestResource`

The first three methods work very well as I expect. The case gets ignored by search when using `findByUsernameIgnoreCase`. The users are correclty found using the given string list in `findByUsernameIn`.

My problem is that I cannot combine `In` and `IgnoreCase` suffixes.
The last two methods also work, but they *don't* ignore case of the string as I want them to do.

Is there a way to perform case insensitive `IN` search not falling back to explicitly specifying the MongoDB `@Query`?

(Tried that with spring-data-mongodb:1.8.4, spring-data-rest-core:2.4.4)

Comment: Have you tried findByUsernameInAllIgnoreCase()?  Not sure it will work, but it is worth a try.

Comment: Yes, same as others, In clause works, 'AllIgnoreCase' is getting ignored. (I'll update the question)

Comment: Are you able to do a standard mongodb query using $in that is case insensitive?  I just wonder if mongoDB supports it directly or not, in case it is mongodb that is ignoring it, rather than Spring data.  Sorry for not trying it myself.

Comment: Didn't try to compose direct MongoDb query with 'In' but a simple case insensitive Mongo query I was able to get working using $regex

Comment: I just stumbled upon the same problem. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: did anyone got the solution i am also facing the same issue... pls help

Comment: I am also facing same issue . did you get the ans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to force case insensitive search is by changing the [collation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/collation/) settings. By default strength is 3. You need to set it to 2, to make it case insensitive.

```
@Query(collation = "{'locale': 'en_US', 'strength': 2}")
Page<User> findByUsernameIn(@Param("username") List<String> username, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Thank you! The collation support was apparently released in Mongodb 3.4 several months after my question. :)